# WSO2 BAM unable to load sub/comparator on Analytic Scripts

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I'm using wso2bam-2.4.0 with external apache-cassandra-2.0.2.

I run wso2 with java option:

```
-Ddisable.cassandra.server.startup=true \
```

When I execute any "insert overwrite table ....", the following error occurs:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-11-22 17:21:59,590]  WARN {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient} -  Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same. {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-11-22 16:58:36,889]  WARN {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner} -  job_local_0001 {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner}
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to load sub/comparator
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.(MapTask.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:211)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your cassandra cluster is not correctly connected with BAM server. Make sure your credentials and IP/port etc are correctly mentioned in Hive script. Or you may mention them correctly in master-datasource.xml. If everything is correct try again with  Cassandra 1.x version.